# arrayUnion is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an object and trying to save it in fireabse version   "^9.18.0" . But i am getting the below error when i using arrayUnion . How can i make it work

```
           var _obj = {};
          _obj["model"] = trimIt(model);
          _obj["quantity"] = trimIt(value['__EMPTY']);
          _obj["type"] = trimIt(value['__EMPTY_1']);
          _obj["company"] = company;
          const values = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
          _obj["key"] = FieldValue.arrayUnion(...values); 
          await addDoc(ref, _obj);


        Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Sh.arrayUnion is not a function
            at Object.eval (dashboard.js:231:29)
            at Function.each (jquery-3.5.1.js:381:19)
            at HTMLButtonElement.eval (dashboard.js:221:1)
```

Comment: No , i have already checked this thread . Anything explicit u want me to try ?

Comment: I tried the below and it worked :

Comment: import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";